# GWT Validation Framework (GWTVF) with gwt 2.3?

Tags: java, validation, gwt

Does GWT VF support gwt 2.3? i tried it and got this exception :

```
ERROR: Uncaught exception escaped. com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: One or more exceptions caught, see full set in UmbrellaException#getCauses
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:129)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.fireEvent(Widget.java:124)
    at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(DomEvent.java:116)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.onBrowserEvent(Widget.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEventImpl(DOM.java:1321)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEvent(DOM.java:1277)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:167)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:326)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:207)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:132)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:214)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor17.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:167)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:281)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:531)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:352)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    javax.validation.ValidationMessages cannot be resolved to a type
    javax.validation.ValidationMessages cannot be resolved to a type
    javax.validation.ValidationMessages cannot be resolved to a type
    javax.validation.ValidationMessages cannot be resolved to a type
    javax.validation.ValidationMessages cannot be resolved to a type
    javax.validation.ValidationMessages cannot be resolved to a type
    javax.validation.ValidationMessages cannot be resolved to a type
    javax.validation.ValidationMessages cannot be resolved to a type
    javax.validation.ValidationMessages cannot be resolved to a type
    javax.validation.ValidationMessages cannot be resolved to a type
    javax.validation.ValidationMessages cannot be resolved to a type
    javax.validation.ValidationMessages cannot be resolved to a type
    javax.validation.ValidationMessages cannot be resolved to a type
    javax.validation.ValidationMessages cannot be resolved to a type
    javax.validation.ValidationMessages cannot be resolved to a type
    javax.validation.ValidationMessages cannot be resolved to a type
    javax.validation.ValidationMessages cannot be resolved to a type
    javax.validation.ValidationMessages cannot be resolved to a type
    javax.validation.ValidationMessages cannot be resolved to a type
    javax.validation.ValidationMessages cannot be resolved to a type
    javax.validation.ValidationMessages cannot be resolved to a type
    javax.validation.ValidationMessages cannot be resolved to a type
    javax.validation.ValidationMessages cannot be resolved to a type
    javax.validation.ValidationMessages cannot be resolved to a type
    javax.validation.ValidationMessages cannot be resolved to a type
    javax.validation.ValidationMessages cannot be resolved to a type
    javax.validation.ValidationMessages cannot be resolved to a type
    javax.validation.ValidationMessages cannot be resolved to a type
    javax.validation.ValidationMessages cannot be resolved to a type
    javax.validation.ValidationMessages cannot be resolved to a type
    javax.validation.ValidationMessages cannot be resolved to a type
    javax.validation.ValidationMessages cannot be resolved to a type
    javax.validation.ValidationMessages cannot be resolved to a type

    at gmgsys.com.webcharge.client.model.MyUserValidator.performValidation(MyUserValidator.java:36)
    at gmgsys.com.webcharge.client.model.MyUserValidator.performValidation(MyUserValidator.java:1)
    at com.google.gwt.validation.client.AbstractValidator.prepareValidation(AbstractValidator.java:171)
    at com.google.gwt.validation.client.AbstractValidator.validateProperty(AbstractValidator.java:78)
    at com.google.gwt.validation.client.AbstractValidator.validateProperty(AbstractValidator.java:64)
    at com.google.gwt.validation.client.AbstractValidator.validate(AbstractValidator.java:52)
    at gmgsys.com.webcharge.client.MainPanel.submitDate(MainPanel.java:181)
    at gmgsys.com.webcharge.client.MainPanel$2.onClick(MainPanel.java:115)
    at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent.dispatch(ClickEvent.java:54)
    at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent.dispatch(ClickEvent.java:1)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent.dispatch(GwtEvent.java:1)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.doFire(SimpleEventBus.java:193)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEvent(SimpleEventBus.java:88)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:127)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.fireEvent(Widget.java:124)
    at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(DomEvent.java:116)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.onBrowserEvent(Widget.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEventImpl(DOM.java:1321)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEvent(DOM.java:1277)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:167)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:326)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:207)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:132)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:214)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor17.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:167)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:281)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:531)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:352)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On their downloads page, the highest listed compatibility version is 2.2, so most likely not yet.

http://code.google.com/p/gwt-validation/downloads/list

Comment: Thansk Brad, that's why i asked because i saw this info :) bad i hope its compatable ...

Comment: I just went and checked, because I had an issue like this when I was developing it, and the front page says GWT Branch 2.1.  Your response was over a year ago so I don't know if 'brakebg' has tried it since.